# Does a given positive measure set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ contains product of two 1 dimensional positive measure set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In $\mathbb{R}^2$ consider the 2 dimensional positive Lebesgue measure set,
$$D=\{re^{it}:t\in[0,2\pi),r\in[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}\}  .   $$
Does there exist sets $A,B\subset\mathbb{R}$ of 1 dimensional positive  Lebesgue measure such that $$A\times B\subset D?$$

Note: The above is not true if $$D=\{(x,y)\in [0,1]\times [0,1]:x-y\notin\mathbb{Q}\}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it there were two such sets $A$, $B$,  then with the map $(x,y) \mapsto (x^2, y^2)$ ($t \mapsto t^2$ bi-Lipschitz on compacts inside $(0, \infty)$) , it would transform into $A_1$, $B_1$ of measure non-zero inside $\{(x,y)\ | \ x+y \not \in \mathbb{Q}^2\}$, which is not possible.

Comment: $r\notin \mathbb{Q}$ doesn't imply $r^2\notin \mathbb{Q}$. Then how we conclude that $D$ maps inside $\{(x,y):x+y\notin \mathbb{Q}\}?$

Comment: I guess of I defined $D$ to be $\{re^{it}:r^2\notin \mathbb{Q}\}$ then your argument works perfectly. Am I right?

Comment: @Oh, I see, it transforms into $x + y \not  \in \mathbb{Q}^2$, and again get a contradiction ( only use $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is dense, and nothing else)

Comment: I am not getting why you need to take $A,B$ away from 0?

Comment: @Prof.Hijibiji: You want to the image not to be of measure $0$. You guarantee that if the inverse $t\mapsto\sqrt{t}$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: is that mean I could get positive measure set $A,B$ (essentially containing 0) such that $A\times B\subset D?$

Comment: @Prof.Hijibiji: No, you can't. If you have some containing $0$, then for sure you will have some away from $0$. Not that hard to see.

Comment: Right you are. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. Just wanted to tell that $0\notin D$ ao we don't need to worry about it.

Comment: @Prof.Hijibiji: No worries!  I modified the answer a bit, hope it is clearer.

Comment: Thanks @orangeskid: bi Lipschitz argument makes it easier to prove but I guess in general if $A$ is positive Lebesgue measure then $A^2=\{a^2:a\in A\}$ is also positive Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ and $B$ be defined by
\begin{align*}
  A & =\big\{a\in\mathbb{R}: a^2=\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i10^{-2i},
a_i\in\{1,2\,\dots,9\}, a^2\not\in \mathbb{Q}\big\} \\
B & =\big\{b\in\mathbb{R}: b^2=\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i10^{-2i+1},
b_i\in\{1,2,\dots,9\}, b^2<\frac12, b^2\not\in \mathbb{Q}\big\}.
\end{align*}
Note that if $r^2=a^2+b^2\in \mathbb{Q}$ then the decimal expansion of
$r^2$ will eventually have a finite length repeating sequence. Any
such sequence would have to come from a unique repeating sequence of
even place decimals from $a^2$ and repeating odd place decimals from
$b^2$. Since $a^2,b^2\not\in \mathbb{Q}$, such repeating sequences do
not exist, thus $r^2\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.  Not entirely sure about the
measure of $A$ and $B$, but for their squares, I think the measures
are positive.

Comment: Actually you need to show that $A\times B\cap D$ is positive Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which could not be true as we can see from the other answer. Thank you for your participation. Appreciation